# MySQL & PHP approach to a query

Tags: php, mysql

I have an items table: itemID, itemName
Each item can be booked for a period of days; there can be multiple bookings for each item; bookings never overlap.

Bookings are held in a bookings table: itemID, startDate, endDate

I want to specify a number of days, start date and end date, then find any items with UNbooked periods which are that number of days or less long, between the provided start date and end date.  In other words, I'm looking for 'short term availability' items within a given date range.  I then want to return a list of the short term availability start and end dates for each itemID.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to go about this, ideally in a single MySQL query but doing it long-hand with PHP loops is fine.

So far my approach would be to get all the unique itemID's in the bookings table with bookings that fall either within or across the provided start and end dates, then parse the overall range with a combination of PHP and MySQL queries, and adding the itemID and the start and end dates of the 'short term period' to an array, but that's not an elegant approach.

Thank you

Comment: Wouldn't using a framework like [CodeIgnighter](http://codeigniter.com/) or [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) make this a lot easier if you're just getting started?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll look at them, but I think in this case what I'm trying to do is expand my SQL query writing competence.

Comment: Even with a framework you'll still be writing a lot of SQL. The idea is they'll do a lot of the routine stuff for you, and usually better than you can do it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Well it all depends on how your dates are structured. If they are in the format DD/MM/YYYY where the values are just an int 03221990 you could attempt to isolate available dates by using simple greater than or less than operators, and that can all be done in a query. That way you could find a range of items that would fit your rough date description but wouldn't necessarily have to comply with exactly your start date and end date. How are your dates structured?

Comment: Unix timestamps, in my opinion, are more portable than something like what you've said. The DATE type is also a good option for MySQL. There's no reason one should use an INT as a date.

Comment: The dates are in MySQL DATE type.

Answer (score 0):

Your bookings table could look like:

```
ItemID | booked
23 | 2012-08-01
23 | 2012-08-02
23 | 2012-08-03
```

Where item 23 is booked for 3 days.  So, add rows as items are booked.

Given the date range 2012-08-03 to 2012-08-05 for each individual date, select those items NOT in the bookings table.  I'm not exactly sure, but I think that could be achieved with a "full outer join".

Comment: That's an interesting idea.  It would mean changing the structure of the table but I'd certainly consider this method when designing a table in future.

Comment: Yeah, it has advantages and disadvantages, but worth considering all the same.  It does not suit every date-centric application, but I like it because it makes getting the data out seem easier.  Thx for the reply.